# Implementing a preceding 0 in an int in c++

Tags: c++, int, cout

I'm trying to display a date after a user inputs it.

So if a user inputs 2010/10/2 as a date, it should change to 2010/10/02, adding a preceding 0 to the int

Here is my relevant code:

Note that I tried setw and setfill and none of them worked.

```
        file.ignore(1);
        file >> year;
        file.ignore(1);
        file >> mon;
        file.ignore(1);
        file >>  std::right>> setw(2) >> setfill('0')  >> day;
```

Comment: Int doesn't have prceding 0. Probably you should use string here.

Comment: You need to display using `setw` and `setfill`, not read it.

Comment: Where's the code to display a date?!

Comment: Integers are values, like the number of fingers I have or the number of days in the year. Only representations of values (like "10") can have a preceding zero. "7", "seven", and "one more than six" are three different representations of the same integer. So it is a category error to ask about an integer with a preceding zero.

Answer (score 0):

You also need `setprecision`, but you need to use it when you print out the result, not when you read.

```
// read the data in:
file >> ignore(1) >> year >> ignore(1) >> mon >> ignore(1) >> day;

// write out the result:
std::cout << std::setfill('0') << std::setprecision(4) << setw(4) << year << "/";
std::cout << std::setprecision(2) << setw(2) << mon << "/";
std::cout << std::setprecision(2) << setw(2) << day << "/";
```

Answer (score 0):

The functions `std::get_time` and `std::put_time` handle optional leading 0s and let you specify the formats pretty easily if you have a [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/get_time) handy:

```
std::tm t{};
std::cin >> std::get_time(&t, "%Y/%m/%d"); // %Y, %m, %d take optional leading 0s
if (std::cin.fail()) {
    // failed to parse date
} else {
    std::cout << std::put_time(&t, "%Y/%m/%d") << '\n'; // %d puts the 0 padding
}
```

Here's a [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/941b88056da61093), with the code only slightly changed from the linked reference.

Answer (score -1):

Every time you read an int, or do anything with an int in C++, it removes all preceding '0's since they're not necessary. Read the input as a string if you want to keep those 0's. Note, this is why things like phone numbers are stored as Strings in databases. It means nothing is lost in conversions

Comment: This is a category error. See my comment to the question. An int *cannot* *possibly* have preceding zeroes.